# Meaning error: Error in if (m < n * p && (m == 0L || (n * p)%%m)) stop(sprintf(ngettext(m, :

Tags: r

I am trying to add a column to a dataframe but get a weird error-message:

> Error in if (m < n * p && (m == 0L || (n * p)%%m)) stop(sprintf(ngettext(m,  : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In n * p : NAs produced by integer overflow
>   2: In n * p : NAs produced by integer overflow

I am executing the line:   `data[ ,extra_columns] <- 0`

Where 'extra_columns' is a character vector. This worked before.

Does anybody knows this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post an minimal reproducible example as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error but it looks like your data is not a data.frame, it is maybe a matrix in this case. Use `str(data)` to check the structure of your data and `data <- as.data.frame(data)` if needed. If not share your data and extra_columns with `dput(data)` and `dput(extra_columns)`.

Comment: str(data)
'data.frame': 3245341 obs. of  3367 variables:

str(extra_colums)
 chr [1:2208]

I cannot share my data because it is highly sensitive data.

Comment: May this be possible because I have such big data?

Comment: I also faced this error before.  Mostly it is because you are doing an operation that is exploding the number of columns in your data-frame.